# How to parse nested JSON and load the data into a table / dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am confused how to use the json library methods and df methods.

I have a json and I am trying to read it as follows:

```
with open(json_path) as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([json_dict]))
    
    df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
    display(df)
    
    requestId   processingTimeInMilliseconds    items
0   123         43                              [{'address': {'countryCode': 'de', 'id': 0}, 'results': [{'values': {'height': 1}, 'requestedId': '1'}, {'values': {'distance': -...
```

---

```
    df2 = pd.json_normalize(json_dict, record_path="items", meta=["requestId","processingTimeInMilliseconds"])
    display(df2)

    results                                                 
0   [{'values': {'height': 1}, 'requestedId': '1'}, {'values': {'distance': -1}, 'requestedId': '2'}, ...

    id  address.countryCode adress.id   requestId   processingTimeInMilliseconds
    1   de                  0           123         43
```

---

```
    df3 = df2.explode('results')
    display(df3)



    results                                            id   address.countryCode address.id  requestId   processingTimeInMilliseconds
0   {'values': {'height': 1}, 'requestedId': '1'}      1    de                  0           123         43
0   {'values': {'distance': -1}, 'requestedId': '2'}   1    de                  0           123         43
```

How should I continue with "results" so that I see all the keys as fields and their values?
Is there a better option/way to do everything in one step so that I unpack/explode all columns.
My aim is that at the end I see all keys from the json as fields and the values in a table.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the original json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following. I provide a function that cn be used on any nested dataframe so you could use it directly for the original dataframe:

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(exploded.columns)  # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

Whit your data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        'results': {'values': {'height': 1}, 'requestedId': '1'},
        'id': 1,
        'address.countryCode': 'de',
        'address.id': 0,
        'requestId': 123,
        'processingTimeInMilliseconds': 43
    },
    {
        'results': {'values': {'distance': -1}, 'requestedId': '2'},
        'id': 1,
        'address.countryCode': 'de',
        'address.id': 0,
        'requestId': 123,
        'processingTimeInMilliseconds': 43
    }
]

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

applying the function

```
flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

returns

```
  index  id address.countryCode  address.id  requestId  \
0      0   1                  de           0        123   
1      1   1                  de           0        123   

   processingTimeInMilliseconds  results.values.height results.requestedId  \
0                            43                    1.0                   1   
1                            43                    NaN                   2   

   results.values.distance  
0                      NaN  
1                     -1.0
```

Comment: For another json I have following error:
Unable to allocate 43.4 GiB for an array with shape (522, 11160261) and data type object. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: Apply the function to chunks of the dataframe and then concatnate the results. Alterntively, use dask and apply the function to the dask dataframe.